# Jdeveloper Migration from 10g to 12C

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am using Jdeveloper10g in my current project. Now I want to migrate it to Jdeveloper12c.
so I download the Jdeveloper12c and open the Jdeveloper10g application into it. 
Before open the application it run the migration tools. which migrate application successfully.
But actual problem arise after migration.

Project Structure :

Service Layer with EJB2.0 (Migrated and deployed successfully)
View
ADF_Module (BC )

In this architecture Service Layer component which has been written in EJB2.0 successfully compiled and deployed with any error.

But View and ADF_module failed for compilation.

In my first R&D I found View and ADF_Module both are dependent to each other . Both are using each other Api.
So when compiler go to compile the view.jpr it does not find ADF_Module class and shows error.

I do not know I to fix this error. Second this structure is compiled on Jdev10g.

Can some one help how to remove this cyclic dependencies or fix this complication error.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is too broad to answer. Normally, the person conducting the upgrade should know how to fix a compilation error, as well resolve any circular dependencies.

Comment: I tried my best to solve this problem but could not solve it. Actually Developer run it on migration tool. and this problem happen only after migration. Other application has same structure on 10g where its work fine. Do not know what to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to move 10 to 11
then 11 to 12.
Each migration does changes in the project settings and 10 to 12 directly is not supported.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I am trying to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your View project should have a dependency on your Model but not the other way around. This can be modified by right click on your project >`Project properties` > `Dependencies` > Use the pencil icon to modify the dependencies.

Comment: But this kind of dependency is working in Jdev10g Perfectly. then why not in Jdev12c.